# Background image css won't show in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, background-image

I'm trying to get the image in my `C:\Images` directory, I've seen css about `background-image: url()` but I can't find a directory based css for that or did I use the wrong css type?

Here's my css so far:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('C:\Images\background.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: did you try using a relative path and copy the image in the same directory as the css file

Comment: Like, you have the image.jpg and style.css in the same folder

Comment: to call the image file you type `url('image.jpg')`

Comment: @Be0wulf I tried putting my `Image` folder as reference and it works but now I'm wondering if it'll work on different workstations since its localhost?

Comment: @Be0wulf Nevermind I'll try your method.

Comment: Of course it will work, that's what relative path is for. You don't have to know the absolute path like `http://example.com/images/image.jpg` the browser will automatically know that you're asking for image.jpg that's on Image folder which is in root directory (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use static paths in your CSS or HTML such as `'C:\Images\background.jpg'` This makes your site non-portable and easy to break.

Always use relative paths when referencing the other files in the site. The browser knows how to resolve the path and requests the full path based on where the site is located.